# Is it possible to parse status field of k8s unstructured. Unstructured

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I'm trying to write a k8s controller. Within the controller I want to parse the YAML file from GitHub to `unstructured. Unstructured`. After parsing, I want to track the status of the applied instance of `unstructured. Unstructured`. The tracking will try to catch if there's a specific key-value.

I failed to do so, since the `unstructured.Unstructured` doesn't have a method for getting status. Then I was trying to marshal it to JSON and find the status, but failed.

If you know a way to achieve these, it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unstructured package provides "Nested" functions.
https://godoc.org/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/unstructured

For status you would use:

```
unstructured.NestedStringMap(myunstruct.Object, "status")
```

For the status message:

```
unstructured.NestedString(myunstruct.Object, "status", "message")
```

See Chapter 4 of **Programming Kubernetes** by Stefan Schimanski and Michael Hausenblas for more discussion of the dynamic client.